# Weblogic domain for physically separated managed servers

Tags: weblogic

I want to create a weblogic cluster that has two managed servers each running on a physically separated remote machine

According to weblogic docs

> All Managed Servers in a cluster must reside in the same domain; you
>   cannot split a cluster over multiple domains.

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24970/understand_domains.htm#DOMCF125

If this is the case then where am I suppose to create the Managed Server on the remote machine. Since the managed server can only be created in the domain, am I not suppose to create the domain on the remote machine for holding managed server?

**[edit]**

As per the below documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e14144/tasks.htm#WLDPU136

It seems that the admin server domain is replicated on remote managed servers using pack and unpack commands.

That means a separate copy of domain must be made available on remote machines in order to operate managed servers on it.

Is it the fault with the oracle documentation- 
Because then its the violation of the Domain Restrictions rule which says that there should be only one domain per cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Domain is logical group for all Weblogic resources like relam, cluster, manged servers. You can create managed servers on physically separated remote machine and group them in a same Weblogic domain.

In a WebLogic Server domain there is always one administration server. This special instance of WebLogic Server is responsible for the configuration of the entire domain. Other servers in the domain are called managed servers. These are typically the servers on which you run your applications. A domain can contain any number of managed servers. You can find the detail on this link -

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e14144/tasks.htm#WLDPU136

Comment: but how do i create a managed server on another machine without creating a domain on that machine.

Comment: In a WebLogic Server domain there is always one administration server. This special instance of WebLogic Server is responsible for the configuration of the entire domain. Other servers in the domain are called managed servers. These are typically the servers on which you run your applications. A domain can contain any number of managed servers. You can find the detail on this link - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e14144/tasks.htm#WLDPU136

Comment: I know but think of a cluster with remotely located managed servers. In which domain will the remote managed server will reside. Since we can not have the managed server without a domain.

Comment: @Vivek You specify the domain (with a complete URL) when you create the managed server on the remote computer. Look at the link provided in above comment.